# Rosdep install dependencies missing

Tags: rosdep, macos, dependencies, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have no idea how to solve this, I did

> rosdep install -a

as a result I get

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
turtlebot_description: Missing resource urdf
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/Users/GCCS/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot
ROS path [2]=/Users/GCCS/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [5]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
turtlebot_bringup: Missing resource app_manager
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/Users/GCCS/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot
ROS path [2]=/Users/GCCS/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [5]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
turtlebot_node: Missing resource tf
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/Users/GCCS/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot
ROS path [2]=/Users/GCCS/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [5]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
pointcloud_to_laserscan: Missing resource nodelet
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/Users/GCCS/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot
ROS path [2]=/Users/GCCS/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [5]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42739/rosdep-install-dependencies-missing/) by [ee05073](https://answers.ros.org/users/2918/ee05073/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-08-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You appear to be missing some core dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0